# Unhelpful error message when doing pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, pivot

When I write the following query:

```
SELECT id,status
FROM dbo.View_Request
PIVOT ( COUNT(id) FOR status IN([CL],[HOLD])) AS pvt
```

I get a vague error message:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near '('.
```

What exactly am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your database is presumably at SQL Server 2000 compatibility level. You need to fix that then you will get these other error messages instead.

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
Invalid column name 'id'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
Invalid column name 'status'.
```

The only columns you will have available to use in the `SELECT` list are `CL` and `HOLD`